# Why is life impossible in the supersymmetric Minkowski vacuum?

Tags: cosmology, universe, supersymmetry, vacuum

I read in several sources that the existence of life is impossible in the supersymmetric Minkowski vacuum (also called the terminal vacuum, the true vacuum or the global minimum). Why? After all, after the decay of a metastable vacuum, particles of their own appear in the supersymmetric Minkowski vacuum, these particles interact. What prevents the emergence of complex systems?

Comment: Which several sources? Which pages?

Comment: @Qmechanic For example, in this article. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0610132 Page 7

Comment: "Vacua with negative cosmological constant also have finite causal diamonds because they contain a big crunch. In the case of false vacua which can decay to Λ = 0, one might think an infinity appears even in the local analysis. Since such vacua must be supersymmetric, they cannot contain observers".

Comment: @JoãoBosco You wrote something completely incomprehensible.

Comment: Are you asking why it is impossible for a living thing to continue to live in a vacuum?

Comment: @Buzz No, I'm saying that when decaying into a supersymmetric vacuum, particles appear. Why can't they form complex structures?

Comment: The only life we know about is the various forms on Earth. I am not familiar with the super-symmetric vacuum in a Minkowski space, Are you assuming that these appearing particles can form suns and planets? Or do you assume that suns and planets are not needed for the creating of life?

Comment: Also I failed to find "Minkowski" mentioned in the multi-verse article you cited.

Comment: @Buzz I don't assume anything. I'm just asking, based on the words of the author of the article. The space with zero cosmological constant is called the Minkowski vacuum.

Comment: The cited article does not mention "Minkowski" or "Minkowski vacuum". I could not find a definition of "Minkowski vacuum" on the  internet. Please post a definition of "Minkowski vacuum" with a citation of a source. What kind of "space" is relevant? What math defines this kind of space?